# Recyclerview's visibility is Visibility. Invisible, still It shows a white backgound on the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have put the recyclerView in xml with visibilitymode invisible. But white space is shown at the place.I have given the xml code for the screen where you can find the visibility property of the RecyclerView. I want to make it visible when any button is pressed below the layout.

I have put the recyclerView in xml with visibilitymode invisible. But white space is shown at the place.I have given the xml code for the screen where you can find the visibility property of the RecyclerView. I want to make it visible when any button is pressed below the layout.

XML CODE: -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout_paint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_paint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:splitMotionEvents="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imd_pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <com.nbagroup.luxuriousframe.UI.CustomViews.PainView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sideMenuView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnChangPhoto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/change_img" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnChangFrame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/frames"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhotoFilter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/photofilter"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnNextPage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/frd_arrow"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: show the xml, and screen capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read at [INVISIBLE tag description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

The tag you want to use is [GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Comment: Hi Igor. Your answer is right. It shows the white background of the top linearlayout. So I have made it transparent. Thanks.